# Convert 2-tuple key in dictionary and add to a new dictionary as a dictionary value

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

So I have the values:

```
values = {(0, 0): 0, (0, 1): 1, (1, 0): 1, (1, 1): 0}
```

and I want to convert the above dictionary to be:

```
values = {0: {0: 0, 1: 1}, 1: {0: 1, 1: 0}}
```

my function:

```
def convert(values : {(int,int): int}) -> {int: {int: int}}:
    dictionary = {}
    l = []

    for k in d.keys():
        l.append(k)

    for k,v in d.items():
        for i in l:
            if i == k:
                dictionary[v] = dict(l)

    return dictionary
```

but I'm getting this as my output instead:

```
values = {0: {0: 1, 1: 1}, 1: {0: 1, 1: 1}}
```

Comment: Are there only 2-tuples? Or can this have an arbitrary depth?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A loop and [`dict.setdefault()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) can do that like:

#### Code:

```
values = {(0, 0): 0, (0, 1): 1, (1, 0): 1, (1, 1): 0}

result = {}
for k, v in values.items():
    result.setdefault(k[0], {})[k[1]] = v

print(result)
```

#### Results:

```
{0: {0: 0, 1: 1}, 1: {0: 1, 1: 0}}
```

Comment: can you explain what is happening in `[k[1]] = v`

Comment: @pyd The `k[1]` fetches the second element of `k`, then the outer `[]` means that that element is used as a key to be assigned the value `v` in the `result` dictionary (actually not directly inside `result`, but inside the dictionary associated with the key `k[0]` of `result`).  Frankly, I hate to see `setdefault`. I'd rather use `collections.defaultdict(dict)`, then that line would simply look like: `result[k[0]][k[1]] = v`. Here you can easily see that it's just a nested assignement.

Answer (score 10):

You just want to group things. The idiomatic way is to use a `defaultdict`:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> values = {(0, 0): 0, (0, 1): 1, (1, 0): 1, (1, 1): 0}
>>> new_values = defaultdict(dict)
>>> for (x,y), v in values.items():
...     new_values[x][y] = v
...
>>> new_values
defaultdict(<class 'dict'>, {0: {0: 0, 1: 1}, 1: {0: 1, 1: 0}})
>>>
```

Comment: Clearer than the accepted answer. You should convert to a dict when you’re done filling it it.

Answer (score 2):

I propose for you a more general approach:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def tree():
    def the_tree():
        return defaultdict(the_tree)
    return the_tree()

t = tree()
for (x, y), z in values.items():
    t[x][y] = z
```

To "close" any node of the tree from further additions, just set its default factory to `None`.  For example, to seal it at the trunk:

```
>>> t.default_factory = None
>>> t[2]
# KeyError
```

Answer (score 2):

A solution for an arbitrary depth:

```
def convert_tupledict(d):
    result = {}
    for ks, v in d.items():
        subresult = result
        *kis, ks = ks
        for ki in kis:
            if ki in subresult:
                subresult = subresult[ki]
            else:
                subresult[ki] = subresult = {}
        subresult[ks] = v
    return result
```

We can then call it with:

```
convert_tupledict({(0, 0): 0, (0, 1): 1, (1, 0): 1, (1, 1): 0})
```

For 2-tuples, the following sulution should be sufficient:

```
def convert_2tupledict(d):
    result = {}
    for (k1, k2), v in d.items():
        result.setdefault(k1, {})[k2] = v
    return result
```